# pygal on windows - cannot access classes from pygal

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygal

I have such short script:

```
import pygal
if __name__ == '__main__':
    bar_chart = pygal.Bar()
```

and following error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Bar'

Do you have any idea what is wrong? Shall I configure some additional paths? I am using windows.

Thank you

Comment: Please use the `{}` button to format your code as code. I've fixed it for you this time.

Comment: I am sorry. I was trying to edit the post but I was not able to find this option :)

Comment: Did you actually _install_ PyGal, or did you just download the source and unpack it into the same directory as your own script?

Comment: I have installed it using easy_install.

Comment: No problem. It may not be obvious to some people (especially Python programmers!) that `{}` means "format as code" until someone tells you.

Comment: Any chance your script is called `pygal.py`, or that you have another file with that name in the same directory (or that you used to, and still have a file named `pygal.pyc`)?

Comment: As a side note, you really shouldn't be using `easy_install` nowadays; use [`pip`](https://pip.pypa.io) instead.

Comment: Thank you for express answers. I am sooo stupid - exactly I have named my script pygal :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your script is named `pygal.py`, when you `import pygal`, it's going to import *your script*, not the `pygal` library you installed into your system site-packages. And your script obviously doesn't have a class named `Bar`.

The solution is simple: rename your script to something different. Like `pygaltest.py` or `mypygal.py`.

And make sure to look at the directory and see if there's a `pygal.pyc` left behind, which Python compiled from your `pygal.py`. If so, you have to delete that file.